# Error to access pdf from s3 with adobe acrobat extension in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, amazon-s3, adobe

After activating the Adobe Acrobat extension on Chrome, I can no longer view pdf files on my website.

In the Edge browser it works normally.

My PDFs are in the S3 bucket.

I noticed that the error happens because the Adobe extension tries to open the file without sending the referer parameter in the request.

My question is whether there is any way to force the referer parameter to be sent in the request, or whether this is a bug in the extension and there is nothing that can be done. Or is there any other way around this?

I tried changing the bucket policy, without success.

I tried changing my link to download the pdf instead of opening it, but to no avail.

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectVersion"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buzz-dev/*",
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {
"aws:Referer": [
"http://127.0.0.1:5173/*",
"https://buzz.dev.inteli.edu.br/*",
"http://localhost:5173/*",
"http://localhost:3000/*",
"https://acrobat.adobe.com/*"
]
}
}
}
]
}